# How to work with axios.put and react?

Tags: react-redux, axios, redux-form

I am trying create a simple crud system with react redux and form-redux.
The code below but does not work and gives error.
First I created an action for update and then created a reducer for that.
And then created component to use the action.

Let me know how to get this to work.

```js
//-------------action--------------

export const EDIT_POST = 'EDIT_POST';
export const editPost = (id) => {
  const request = axios.put(`${BOOK_URL}/books/${id}`);
  return {
    type: EDIT_POST,
    payload: id,
  }
};
//---------------- reducer-----------------
case EDIT_POST: {
      return {...state, post: action.payload.data}
    }
    
//----------------route--------------

          <Route path='/posts/edit/:id' component={PostEdit}/>


//-------------------PostEdit---------------


class PostEdit extends Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.editPost(this.props.match.params.id);
    console.log(this.props.editPost(this.props.match.params.id));
  };
  renderField = field => {
    const {meta: {touched, error}} = field;
    const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;
    return (
      <div className='has-danger'>
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <input type="text" {...field.input} className="form-control"/>
        <div className="text-help">
          {touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmitForm)}>
        <Field name="title" label="Title" component={this.renderField}/>
        <Field name="author" label="Author" component={this.renderField}/>
        <Field name="description" label="Description" component={this.renderField}/>
        <Field name="publicationDate" label="PublicationDate" component={this.renderField}/>

        <button type='submit' className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default  reduxForm({
 form :'updateForm'
})(connect(null, {editPost})(PostEdit));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is not enough info or the question is not clear

Comment: sorry i upload my files please lock at them tanx
https://ufile.io/54ct4

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell what error you are getting?

You have to change your action like

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(`${BOOK_URL}/books`).then((response) => {
            return dispatch({
                type: FETCH_POSTS,
                payload: // your response here
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: tell payload is undefinde